# Why a 302 Redirect response when I expect 200 OK

Tags: asp.net, web-config, forms-authentication, iis-express

TLDR

The web site I am hired for to maintain handles security in two places: web.config Forms-authentication, and by checking the Session cookie in code-behind in the MasterPage. So changing security details, like making some pages accessible without login, requires changes at `both` places. Just forget about one, and strange things happen in the network dev tools...

---

My web site is working really nice, but the small problems left keep me puzzled. It uses Forms authentication, but all files in the root are unrestricted; only some directories have `deny users=?` in the local web.config. Still, asp pages in the root cannot be accessed before login, and respond with a `302 Found, Redirect`.

This is part of web.config in the root:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name="MYWEBAPP.ASPXAUTH" loginUrl="~/Welkom.aspx"
    protection="All" timeout="181" slidingExpiration="true" path="/"/>
</authentication>
```

and there is no `<authorization>` section.

The user is supposed to be allowed, before login, to visit pages like /Cookies.aspx, but with the FireFox F12 Dev Tools, tab Network, I see a response of 302, followed by a redirection to /Login.aspx.

This leads to two questions:

1. why 302, and not simply 200 OK and show the Cookies page?
2. why going to /Login.aspx and not /Welkom.aspx?

I admit that the Welkom.aspx might look strange here, but it worked nice for years, and it does a `Response.Redirect("/Login.aspx")` if a suitable url is in the query params. But I checked with a debugger breakpoint in Page_Load(), and in the above questions, the Welkom.aspx.cs is NOT visited, so somehow the IIS(Expr) goes straight to /Login.aspx, very strange.

Comment: Have you searched for text "Login.aspx" in your project to check if there is a redirect to Login.aspx?

Comment: @MohsinMehmood Good point. I already found something in the master page. The problem is now practically solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not about how HTTP works, but about my own code somewhere in the MasterPage code-behind that called Response.Redirect(). When your code base is getting large, such human errors creep in. So there is nothing technical to learn from this question.